# A general question on Galois theory: cyclotomy

Tags: group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory

Say we that we have a $pth$ root of unity where $p>2$ is prime. Let $E=\Bbb Q(w)$ and let $\alpha=w+w^{-1}$.

I want to figure this question out asked on a past exam:

1)   Compute | E : $\Bbb Q(α)$ |, and |$\Bbb Q(α)$ : $\Bbb Q$|.

If $w$ is a primitive pth root of unity then it's Galois grouo over $\Bbb Q$ is $\Bbb Z/p \Bbb Z \cong C_{p-1}\cong C_i\times……\times C_2.$ By the Chinese remainder theorem. We see that $\alpha$ must be fixed by a transposition of the elements $w^1,w^{p-1}$. So we choose the automorphism $\phi:w\rightarrow w^{p-1}$ which is order two as $\phi(w^{p-1})=w^{p^2-2p+1}=w$. The subgroup of automorphism fixing $\alpha$ then is $\langle \phi^{p-1}\rangle \cong C_2.$ And so by Galois Correspondence   $| E : \Bbb Q(α) |=2$ while |$\Bbb Q(α)$ : $\Bbb Q|=p/2$.

2) It says find the Galois group  $G = Gal(E/\Bbb Q(α))$? But I did that in the first part infact I don't see another way to determine part (1) then by determining the group first, Is there ?

3)What are the isomorphisms in $G=Gal(\Bbb Q(α)/ \Bbb Q)?$ i.e. How do they act on $α?$

By the Fundamental theorem of Galois $Gal(\Bbb Q(α)/ \Bbb Q)= \cong\tfrac{Gal(E/F)}{Gal(E/Q(\alpha)}$ so $Gal(\Bbb Q(α)/ \Bbb Q)\cong C_{p-1}/C_2$.

This part confuses me, specifically because if we consider factors $C_{p-1}/C_2$
over different $p$ then we get different groups So I  don't understand how this  can be considered generally . Unless the question is asking you to deduce it in some other manner . In which case I Know we could say that isomorphisms in $G$ are those which fix $\Bbb Q $ but not $\Bbb Q(\alpha)$. But this a trivial.

Any advice anyone ?

Comment: As $w^{p-1}=w^{-1}=\overline{w}$, we see that $\phi$ is the restriction of the usual complex conjugation - a point exploited in Gerry Myerson's answer. Quotients of a cyclic group are themselves cyclic. And if you know what an automorphism does to $w$ it is easy to figure out what it does to $\alpha$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen the thing that confuses me though is that say we had p=5 then the quotient would give $C_2$ and the automorphism would again be the group generated by $\langle \phi^{p-1} \rangle$ (as all the other automorphism generate $C_4$ wo we'd have complex conjugation acting on $\alpha$ but if we had instead p=7 ,the Galois group of the entire extension becomes $C_3\times C_2$ and now giving the quotient of $C_2$ would give $C_3$ (right ?) so then we wouldn't have complex conjugation. And FTSOG say that  it was $C_2$ there are now two choices for $C_2$  the quotient so which to choose ?

Comment: No, if $\sigma$ is a generator of $C_n$ then its coset is the generator of all the quotient groups $C_n/H$. The automorphism $\phi:w\mapsto w^{p-1}$ cannot generate the Galois group $Gal(\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)/\Bbb{Q})$ because it was moded out when forming the quotient group. In the case $p=5$ the automorphism $\tau:w\mapsto w^2$ generates $Gal(\Bbb{Q}(w)/\Bbb{Q})$ so its restriction to the subfield $\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)$ generates the quotient group $Gal(\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)/\Bbb{Q})$. Remember, the Galois group of a smaller intermediate field is a quotient group, not a subgroup.

Comment: Or, $C_4$ is not generate by anyone of its non-trivial elements. The square of a generator only generates a proper subgroup. What you claim only works in $C_n$ when $n$ is a prime.

Comment: Also, the choice of generator does not matter much. Again, in the case $p=5$, the other generator of $C_4$ is $\tau^3:w\mapsto w^3$. Guess what, the restrictions of $\tau$ and $\tau^3$ to the subfield $\Bbb{Q}(w+w^{-1})$ coincide. This is because they differ from each other by complex conjugation fixing $\Bbb{Q}(w+w^{-1})$ elementwise.

Comment: In the case $p=7$ you can equally well think of the Galois group as $C_6$ (isomorphic to $C_3\times C_2$. So it has a single subgroup of order two, and hence there is no choice in the quotient group.

Comment: I need to commute next. If I find the time I will try and post an answer hopefully clearing most of the fog.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, I wouldn't bother; the user asked the same question previously, I gave hints in comments, e.g. "what elements of [the Galois group] fix $\alpha$?" as well as stressing it was important to think of the Galois group not only abstractly but as a concrete group acting on the roots of unity [this is neccesary to be able to understand what the quotient is]. I only received belligerent comments in return until the user deleted the question and posted it again here with modifications. The user claims they are "eager to learn" but I haven't seen much indication of that in their actions.

Comment: @user687721 I think that's a pretty one sided take on things, I said I didn't understand what was happening, you answered with me with a question that I clearly couldn't answer given that my post clearly indicated that I didn't understand the material well enough, I did try to keep up with what you were saying and to answer and in response you said you thought that I was barely understandable even in English, to which I replied if I understood how to answer all the questions you were asking I wouldn't have bothered asking. So I think if anyone was belligerent it was you. But I think it would

Comment: be extremely petty to continue some kind of feud on math stack exchange so if you prefer just don't reply to my questions anymore.I didn't bother getting into argument about how I felt you were speaking,because you're just somebody somewhere looking at a screen but I feel I've to draw attention to what actually happened if you are going to discourage people from helping me.I can undelete the post if anyone wants to see but I doubt anyone would care enough.

Comment: The reason I deleted the question by the way is because after thinking about it I came up with a more detailed question(the first just said I didn't understand how to do it not specific confusions)

Comment: The fact that you just went on a three comment rant but haven't responded to the two people who have provided answers says everything you need to know. Rest assured, I won't make the mistake of trying to help you again!

Comment: @user687721 I responded to Jyrki because his was the answer I understood the best. I don't consider it help to ask me questions I've specifically stated I can't answer and then to  insult me about my English, I feel it was needlessly condescending and not nice.

Comment: Here's some honest advice. You wrote a confusing question. That's fine; when students are confused they often ask confusing questions. Take this question: you say the Galois group of $E$ is $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbf{Z})$ (it's not),  that it isomorphic to $C_{p-1}$ (it is), and that $C_{p-1}$ is isomorphic to $C_i \times \ldots C_2$ which is a both incoherent and wrong; if $p = 5$ then $C_4$ is cyclic and has no $C_2$ factor). Later you implicitly claim that $[E:\mathbb{Q}] = p$ when it is $p-1$. Maybe these indicate a lack of understanding, maybe they are typos, it's not easy for us to know.

Comment: The usual response is to probe the understanding of a student by asking questions to determine what they actually know. In that case, I stressed the importance of thinking of the Galois group of $E$ not as an abstract cyclic group of order $p-1$, but as a very specific group $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ which has a canonical action on the roots of unity. Then I asked if you knew how to work out what elements of $G$ fixed $\alpha$. Your response was "That's exactly what my question is, If I knew how to do it then why would I ask."

Comment: You need to realize that you have overestimated how well you convey what confuses you. *On this very question* you say "the subgroup of automorphism fixing $\alpha$ then is $\langle \phi^{p-1} \rangle \simeq C_2$". But aren't you then claiming to know the answer to exactly my question, namely the elements which fix $\alpha$ are the identity and $\phi^{p-1}$? The key point of this question is how to determine why your assertion (the one in quotes above) is true --- you certainly don't justify it.

Comment: Ultimately, a little self-awareness that your question may be phrased in a confusing and incoherent manner which makes it very unclear what you understand and what you don't understand would go a long way.

Comment: @user687721 It's a fair point that my question may have been confusing, I've been having many long nights from study so it might have been a little incoherent , my point is that there was no need to insult me about my English, there's usually no reason to insult someone at all . I was trying to follow what you were saying before that even though it was going above my head. But those are my last words on the matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how to find the degree of $E$ over ${\bf Q}(\alpha)$ without finding the group.

$\omega$ satisfies a quadratic with coefficients in ${\bf Q}(\alpha)$, namely, $\omega^2-\alpha\omega+1=0$, so the degree we're looking for is either $1$ or $2$. But $\omega$ is not real, while $\alpha$ is (and, hence, all elements of ${\bf Q}(\alpha)$ are), so the degree can't be $1$, so it must be $2$.

Answer (score 1):

The Galois group for the extension of **Q** generated by a primitive $m$-th root of unity  is the group of units of **Z**$/m$**Z**. which has order $\phi(m)$  and is cyclic when $m$ is a prime number.

Your number $\alpha =w+ \bar w$ has $(p-1)/2$ distinct conjugates and so has $(p-1)/2$ as its degree.
(Hint: Apply all the $p-1$ automorphisms to $\alpha$ and see that every value is repeated once)

By General Galois theory the Galois group of the upper extension is the subgroup of the Galois group fixing the intermediate field.

Now everything should be easy.